# Less bulky ratchet strap to tie two hexagonal dumbbells

Tags: fastener

What kind of tie could I use to tie two dumbbells of roughly the same size ?
[image: hexagonal dumbbells]
I tried the typical auto ratchet strap but it's really bulky - I don't like that huge piece of metal hanging on the side.

[image]

There is also a lighter version of that strap used on bikes, but there is no mechanical advantage to tension the strap, so it doesn't work properly. The dumbbells slide on each other.

[image]

Ideally I'm looking for something the size of the bike version that would also have a strong ratchet mechanism to tension the strap. I didn't find anything that fits those criteria on amazon.

I'm not looking for a different solution to increase the load, as I want to keep it simple.
Something easily removable would be preferable, but I can go with something semi permanent that would require a tool if it makes the the weights stick together more firmly

The bottom weight is in the 20..25 kg range, (45 to 55 lbs), so this is the weight that both ties will have to lift, i.e 12.5 kg per tie max.

Comment: Will you take it on and off eg to carry them home daily? Or is it for a long term storage?

Comment: *but there is no mechanical advantage to tension the strap* - there is some if you wrap it round twice but this may be defeated some if the dumbbells are rubber coated

Answer (score 2):

**The Tie-One-On Lifehack:**

The lightest, strongest, least expensive, adjustable, strap to tie things together is the lowly cable-tie, aka zip-tie, ty-wrap, etc.

They are available in different lengths from 4" to 60" and weights (HD, Jumbo). The 'buckle' is tiny compared to any other strap buckle or cinch.

Normally, hand-tightening is okay for most applications; but, for a few dollars an inexpensive modified pliers that tighten the plastic strip securely with little effort.

[image: Cable-tie tensioner]

Nylon is the usual material for cable-ties but stainless steel is also available.

After you attach your weights together, you can get or make a cable-tie release to loosen the semi-permanent assembly.

[image: Cable-tie opener]

You can also buy bags of ties to be discarded rather than opened and reused. If you trim off the tail of the tie after it has been tightened, it's not re-useable. It can't be put into the tightener pliers as there's nothing left to grip.

Unless you rarely assemble and tear-down your weights, discarding the ties is a bad environmental practice.

[Update] Some are made to be re-useable and have quick release built-in.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Hose Clamp]
Stainless steel hose clamp.

This looks like a good solution because it is easy to disassemble with minimal tools, can be cut to length to fit my needs, has plenty of other use, has a mechanical advantage, and the footprint is really small.

Comment: +1 Note that this was designed for round objects. The weights aren't quite round which may prevent your first try from being tight enough. You might also consider a combination of ideas. Use a strong band to keep the weights together and a light band of something like masking tape to hold the strong band from slipping out of position if the tension in the strong band is (or becomes) insufficient.

Comment: Do you mean that the strap will catch on the rubberized angles of the hexagons and prevent it from tightening ?

Comment: Where I come from, this is called a Jubilee Clip.

Comment: Looks like it's called like that in the UK (Jubilee Clip)

Answer (score 0):

**The Pull Yourself Together Lifehack:**

A heavy-duty cinch belt with Velcro™ hold may be the solution to the question.

[image: heavy duty cinch belt]

Good luck.

Comment: There is no mechanical advantage to tension the belt before closing it though. Or maybe there is a 2:1  because of the ring, I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Using "narrow ratchet straps" at first, followed by "1 inch ratchet straps" provided a number of links more suited for your purposes. The first thing that popped into my alleged mind is that they are directed to motorcycle use, which allows for lower strength requirements than those used to secure loads on semi-trailers. A later search using "motorcycle ratchet straps" also provided useful results. I suspect there are no products with widths smaller than one inch.

Representative sample from one such page, [Shippers Supplies](https://www.shipperssupplies.com/1-inch-custom-ratchet-strap-with-s-hooks/):

[image: one inch ratchet strap]

Linked site provides eight to thirty feet options. The mechanism is less bulky than the OP photo for obvious reasons.

Amazon lists many 1.5" straps and at least one 1 inch strap option, found with the "motorcycle ratchet straps" search on [that site](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MBB15KM):

[image: Amazon ratchet strap]

Answer (score 0):

I use Kevlar belts with two D rings (one on each end). Loop around the dumbbells, then I attach an Angles90 style grip to the D rings. Works well for deadlifts and rows. I haven't tried benching with them yet though